# How to find the list of resources an app registry is part of in azure?

Tags: azure

Very new to Azure.

I want to see all resources using specific enterprise applications or application registrations.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way yet to find this, unfortunately. Here's a tedious approach I've taken before - if you are a Global Admin or have access to one, try to derive the applications/users that are using the app by looking under the Enterprise Application sign-in logs. Since these represent instances of your application being used, I believe this could help you identify where it has been used recently.

As you can see this might work if you're only investigating for one App. If you have tons of them, not so convenient.